# Using a colon (:) in return URL with Forms Authentication ("The return URL specified for request redirection is invalid")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, returnurl

I am getting the error "The return URL specified for request redirection is invalid" when using forms authentication. I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/cf27c390-07b1-4a48-b337-130a8e220069) that says this is a known issue with return URLs that contain colons (mine indeed contains a few).

The workaround in that thread is to catch the error and use a default return URL ... hardly an acceptable solution. I can try to avoid colons in URLS, but that's a bit of a pain.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: did you tried any helper class for encode `:`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon is a reserved character, per the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). You can't put an unencoded `:` in the query or hash of a URI, period.

So you need to %-encode the colon.

Comment: In my defense, I'm simply working through Asp.net MVC ... I would expect it to do this encoding for me.

return RedirectToAction("Show", "Tasks", new {from=someDateObject});

Comment: Generally, it should. There may be cases it misses. I'd have to look at the specifics.